# How to prevent Powershell from assuming 80 columns width output when redirecting output on Linux

Tags: powershell

When i execute the following PowerShell script on Linux:

```
dir
```

In the following way:

```
pwsh test.ps1 > output.txt
```

The output in `output.txt` is limited to 80 columns.

How can i prevent this behavior? Modifying `$host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize` is not supported on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `pwsh` with output redirected will just assume a standard file width.

But you can set a width *inside* `pwsh`.

```
PS> .\test1.ps1 | Out-File z -Width 60
```

or

```
pwsh -c ".\test1.ps1 | Out-File z -Width 60"
```